# validation css for select boxes

Tags: jquery, css, validation

I am just finalising our form validations, and we fire css at input elements etc if they do not validate.

But not sure how to combat this for elements other than input.

For example, selects and radio and checkboxes.

Typically our js for this is :

For an Email field.

```
if(email == "") $('#email').css({"background":"#efefef","border":"1px solid #F12B63"});
```

just not sure why the css validation ( error ) does not work on select elements radios and checkboxes... any suggestions. Validation works, just not the css part

Comment: AFAIK, u cant style checkboxes and radiobuttons background or borders.

Comment: yer i think for these we are gonna have to fire a message, more so the selects thats doin me head in

Comment: You could try my answer though, i think its the closest youll get to a border directly on the checkboxes/radios

Answer (score 2):

Try with the outline attribute instead: http://jsfiddle.net/Kqcx7/1/

Comment: tried this, but not working for us. I am kind of thinking disable submit button unless the checkboxes are ticked

Answer (score 1):

The border property will not work for all form elements. You have to add a wrapper span/div around the select boxes. Alternative approach is to use outline property.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** You can change label color instead of changing input border.

**Option 2:** Use javascript, css and images to change appearance of checkboxes and radio buttons. There are a lot of tutorials.

let say you have this form:

```
<form method="post" action="/path/to/action" id="exampleForm">
  <div id="fullNameBlock">
    <label>Full Name:</label><input type="text" value="" name="fullname" >
  </div>
  <div id="emailBlock">
    <label>Email:</label><input type="text" value="" name="email" >
  </div> 
  <input type="submit" value="Send" >
</form>
```

and let say you validate on submit:

```
if( !validate() ) {

}
```

and your email is wrong.
One option is to do something like this:

```
$("#emailBlock").find("label").css({color: "red"});
```

Also you can add a hidden message below the input:

```
<div id="emailBlock">
  <label>Email:</label><input type="text" value="" name="email" > <br>
  <span style="display:none;">Your email is invalid</span>
</div>
```

and show the message when there is an error:

$("#emailBlock").find("span").show();

You can check these guides for custom checkboxes and radio buttons:

http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/
http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2006/06/11/fancy-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/
http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/customized_html_controls_creating_custom_checkbox.aspx
http://blogs.digitss.com/javascript/jquery-javascript/jquery-fancy-custom-radio-and-checkbox/

Comment: I added an example and some links, hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery you can simply change the border of the select (dropdown) input.

```
$('#selectId').parent().css('border-color','red');
```